# Preview with another theme

Tags: 7, theming, entities

I'd like to preview using a different theme, but I'd like the admin theme to be used for everything else related to content editing and creation.

I've tried out the "pageview" module, but it does not work the way I expect it to.  This could be related to a conflict with other modules related to themes, such as Role Theme Switcher and Mobile redirection tools.

Comment: Check out my answer in this post: [124154](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/124154)

Answer (score 2):

You may find the [ThemeKey](http://drupal.org/project/themekey) module useful.  This module allows you to define arbitrary rules to determine when to show each theme.  You can make as simple or as complex a configuration as you want.

From the module page, the following features are supported:

> - individually-styled channels
> - a front-page / "splash" screen
> - a date/time-selected Christmas theme
> - mobile themes for different auto-detected mobile devices
> - special themes for "limited" or "old" browsers
> - content, user, or role -specific themes
> - indicating your environment (production, staging, testing, sandbox, … )
> - testing your redesign safely on a live server

See the documentation for more details.

Comment: Thanks. I don't see an option specifically for preview (nor is it mentioned anywhere in the docs that I can see).

I've done this with the a path.  I've got the pagepreview module installed, which generates an iframe with a src of "pagepreview/%" .  Checking for that path with themekey seems to work.

Comment: @jdu What exactly do you mean by preview?  Do you mean give a certain set of user(s) access to theme ABC?  If so, create a "preview_theme" role, add it to the appropriate users, and then add rules in Theme Key-- one rule to set the theme to the theme to be previewed, and then another to keep content editing paths, etc. as the admin theme for that role.