# Real-time preview of node/form in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, theming, javascript, entities

I'm trying to achieve this in Drupal 7. This is what I need [URL](http://www.vistaprint.in/vp/ns/studio3.aspx?template=508554_AHT_AK8_B5L_AKD_AJX) for working example (But its not in **Drupal**).

**Requirement - Live Preview with alignment features**

[image: Requirement - Live Preview]

From Drupal.Stackexchange I've came across this post [29325](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29325/) where the user is trying to achieve the similar thing there its mentioned about the Drupal's [Live](https://www.drupal.org/project/live) Module but as the description page of the module shows yet its not made up for Drupal 7 and I'm sure this will not fulfill my requirement.

## **Question:**

1. Rather than Drupal's Live module, is there any other module available?
2. Can any of the JS/jQuery plugin or library or framework can fulfill my above mentioned requirement?

**Note**

- I've created the left/side panel form using the custom content type hence now, if I can achieve this live preview using some JS plugin/library also then I'm fine with it as I can see that no Drupal module is available for this!

Comment: Perhaps you can use https://www.drupal.org/project/edit

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @undersound, but as you can see its too different from what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a real time preview not an in-line editor, in the sense what I want is when I'm trying to create a node, I should get the preview of that node in real-time with a feature of dragging and dropping the elements.

Comment: I highly doubt that you will find a module that fits your requirements exactly. This should not be too hard with a little javascript. Use form_alter on your node edit form, add div elements or a canvas for the preview, attach javascript listeners on your inputs, then write the javascript that listens and populates the preview when the inputs change.

Answer (score 1):

I have started development of a module - [Live preview](https://www.drupal.org/project/live_preview) which might be more along the lines of what you're after.

> This module provides a more comprehensive, genuine and interactive version of the built-in node preview feature.
>
> The live preview feature requires JavaScript; if JavaScript is disabled it will not apply its triggers, effectively retaining the built-in preview.

It hasn't yet reached a stable release, but it's worth checking out (-dev version should work just fine).